# Was was the plan that Llewelyn Moss had for 'the last man standing'?

Tags: no-country-for-old-men

In ***No Country for Old Men***, when Llewelyn Moss discovers that the money isn't in the cars, he comes to the conclusion that the last standing man probably took it with him. He then decides to go after him.

What was he planning to do once he encountered him? Kill him? Llewelyn doesn't look like a guy who would go to that length to procure money. He feels guilty about not giving a dying Mexican gangster some water! So what was his plan?

Comment: Wasn't there also a blood trail? So perhaps he suspected that this last man was possibly heavily wounded and perhaps wouldn't make it that far.

Comment: I remember there being a blood trail of the wounded dog that leads to the group of cars. I always assumed the 'tracks' he follows to the 'last man standing' were his footprints. This might explain it.

Answer (score 3):

**He came armed.  He planned on using lethal force if need be.**

Llewelyn surmised from the drugs and the corpses that a deal had gone sour.  He tracked the remaining party from the trail of blood.

He took mercy on the victim in the car because he was suffering; Llewelyn had a conscience.  But he also had enough curiosity to take the rest of his afternoon to track the remaining party.  Judging from the amount of dope, there would be a high reward at the end of the blood trail.

He also surmised that the remaining party (only one man he learned) was wounded, and so waited him out from afar.  When he witnessed no movement over a long period of time, he felt safe enough to approach.

If the remaining party were instead multiple men, he'd have a decision to make.  Likely he would have tracked them until he found an opportunity to separate them from the money, or until they let natural selection whittle the party to one.

With only one healthy party left, he'd have to weigh his conscience.  He wasn't an evil man, as we witnessed.  But on the other hand, this is likely more money than he's ever seen.  I wager he would have tracked a single man until he could have disarmed him and then taken the money.

Comment: How did he surmise that the remaining party was wounded? Is it as BCdotWEB said, he was following the blood trail of the remaining party? How did you come to that conclusion? They never show what he was following right?

Comment: He learned both from the blood in the trail and also by observing him with binoculars.

Comment: Just re-watched the scene and there is no blood, only what seem like car tire tracks...